what would this arctan equation be in R
What would this arctan equation be in R.  I'm unsure how to format this equation in R.  Any expert help
B1 = arctan[0.152 * (Var1 + 8.3136)^(1/2)]

Use atan for $arctan$.

What about help.search("arctan")?
